# how to handle multiple ASIFormDataRequest - iphone development

Tags: iphone, frameworks

I am using ASIFormDataRequest to send http requests but they all go to the same function requestFinished. Inside this function how can I know from which request it came from? Is there any way for me to add some kind of tag name to request that comes in?

I would prefer to use one function and have a switch statements instead of having two functions per http requests and manually setting the functions
    [request setDidFailSelector:@selector(requestFailed:)];
    [request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestFinished:)];

ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
 [request setDelegate:self];
 [request startSynchronous];

- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subclass `ASIFormDataRequest` or wrap an instance of it in a utility class. You then add your own `tag`-like property to instances of your subclass or wrapper object.